# javascript array 8>50 return true

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, return, bubble-sort

can someone explain me, why does javascript return true?  The array is global defined.

```
  console.log(arr[j] + ">" + arr[j + 1]); // 8>50
  console.log(arr[j] > arr[j + 1]);       // true
```

This happens only for numbers<10, For Example does 22>10 return true.

I need it in my bubbleSort algorithm and fixed this with `parseInt(arr[j])>parseInt(arr[j+1])` , but i think there will be better solutions.

Thanks a lot!:)

Comment: You have an array of strings

Comment: it looks, you are sorting strings. you could take an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) instead of `parseInt` (this requires a base as well for some numbers).

Comment: Thanks a lot @adiga! :) Now i can find a solution! :)

Comment: If you want to make it a bit shorter, use the [Unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) opeartor: `+arr[j] > +arr[j+1]`

Comment: I solved it with a convert from the string array to a array of numbers.
`arr = arr.map((arr) => +arr);`

Comment: Or use number as a callback to map like this:`arr.map(Number)`